# almost infinite columns

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to create different sets of questions and store the answers

this is what i tried

**table questions**
id, name

**table fields**
id, label

**table relations**
id, question_id, field_id

this works great but only for the display part of the questions
but what about storing the answers? i can't store answers horizontally because i don't have a reference (col names), and vertically will be very bad for the database right?

im using mysql. what will be the best way to do this? thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add 1 more table to store answer :

```
question_id  PK   INT
user_id      PK   INT <-- or maybe anything that identifies the user
field_id     PK   INT
answer            VARCHAR <-- or TEXT , depends on your usage
```

To return all results ( assume the answer table is named as `tbl_answer` ):

```
SELECT `c.name` AS question, b.label, answer FROM tbl_answer a 
LEFT JOIN fields b ON a.field_id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN questions c ON a.question_id=c.id
```

To return the result of specific user:

```
SELECT `c.name` AS question, b.label, answer FROM tbl_answer a 
LEFT JOIN fields b ON a.field_id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN questions c ON a.question_id=c.id 
WHERE user_id={user id here}
```

To return the result of specific question:

```
SELECT `c.name` AS question, b.label, answer FROM tbl_answer a 
LEFT JOIN fields b ON a.field_id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN questions c ON a.question_id=c.id 
WHERE question_id={question id here}
```

Of course, you have to further process the result .

Comment: And how can i build a query to return all the submissions? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

You just need another table to store answers in:

## Answers

id
question_id
field_id (answer)

You'll probably also need one more field to associate your "Answer" with something, like a person or a questionnaire being answered.

Comment: yes. this is the obvious aproach i think. but if i do this i will have a row for each answer!